# Startup at login screen crashes

Tags: drivers, display, intel-graphics, i915

At Ubuntu 23.10 Mantic Desktop login screen the display will change to flashing horizontal colored lines or display block artifacts at the login screen.

> Celeron N5105 Intel UHD Graphics 24 EUs (Jasper Lake)

After about 20 seconds of displaying the messed up screen the system reboots.

I've tried loading from Live versions and also installing earlier versions of Ubuntu and Fedora with the same result.

```
lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 vga
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation JasperLake [UHD Graphics] [8086:4e61] (rev 01)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Video
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation JasperLake [UHD Graphics] [8086:2212]
```

Any ideas or has anyone seen similar behavior with integrated Intel graphics using the i915 driver?

Comment: So I have discovered the crash is due to ram. Using both memory sticks the PC will crash. Booting with a single stick in either slot (the board has 2 DIMM slots) the PC will start normally. I've tested each stick separately in either ram slot. It's when both ram slots are used the system will crash.

I've also run Memtest with full 4 passes with no errors. Could this be a mainboard problem or the CPU?